# JavaScript Object is not assigned properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, javascript-objects

I'm unable to understand why this happens

**I'm using React to create a web app**

I've a Javascript object called `user_info`

```
var user_info = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
    f_name: ''
};
```

Now I want to assign these values to the ones that I fetch from my firebase Realtime Database.

```
 db.ref("/users").on("value", snapshot => {                           
            
            alert("Firebase " + snapshot.child("username").val()) // Got the value correctly.....

            user_info.username = snapshot.child("username").val();
            user_info.password = snapshot.child("password").val(); //Assigning it to the object...
            user_info.f_name = snapshot.child("f-name").val();
            
            alert("Firebase Username = " + user_info.username); //Assigned Successfully...
           
        });
```

After this block of code (outside the `snapshot function`), I use the `alert()` to display the username again.

```
alert(user_info.username); // No value is displayed here.
```

I guess that the value from the snapshot is not assigned to the object `user_info`. Later I'm exporting this object and importing it in another file where I face the same problem.

```
export {user_info};
```

--- In the Other file ---------

```
import React from 'react';
import {user_info} from './users.js';

function LandingPage()
{
  return(
      <div className="container">
         <h1>Welcome {user_info.username}</h1> // Only 'Welcome' is displayed
      </div>
   );
}

export default LandingPage;
```

I can't understand why the value is not assigned to the Object `user_info`. Please correct my code so that I could store the value in my object.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

value is updated but component is not rerendered use state (useState hook) here then render it from state.
and use useEffect hooks for updating state when "user_info" is updated.

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {user_info} from './users.js';

function LandingPage()
{
const [userInfo,setUserInfo]=useState({});

useEffect(()=>{
setUserInfo(user_info);
},[user_info]);


  return(
      <div className="container">
         <h1>Welcome {userInfo?.username}</h1> // Only 'Welcome' is displayed
      </div>
   );
}

export default LandingPage;
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html